# Как сделать фигурное обтекание текста?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хочу чтоб текст имел такие же отступы как и на макете, например первая строчка 15 слов самая длинная, вторая строчка средняя 9 слов, а третья 5 слов.  Ну вообщем как пирамида перевернутая была. Как на картинке  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня почему-то так выходит.

Comment: Откуда вы пример взяли?

Comment: как минимум надо поставить text-align: center

Comment: @StackOverflow из макета, вот побольше картинка https://imgur.com/YE506Om

Comment: Не вижу причин не использовать самый обыкновенный `<br/>`

Comment: @andreymal мне нужно чтоб текст был форме перевернутой пирамиды как на картинке выше, а не был в форме квадрата где не имеет отступов начало предложения.  Да я могу использовать  `<br>`  но тогда текст не будет иметь отступов

Comment: @Остин отступы делаются элементарно через `text-align: center` же

Comment: @andreymal ой, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно перенести все вручную с `<p>`/`<br>`, можно использовать CSS свойства: `shape-outside` или `shape-inside`, о них можно почитать хотя бы [тут](https://htmlhook.ru/podrobno-o-css-shapes.html).

Comment: IE, Edge, FF не поддерживают  shape-outside и shape-inside

Comment: @Air IE в 2017 :) Тем не менее эти браузеры не сильно популярны, я бы сказал вовсе не популярны, хотя мозилла что-то там и делает. Поддержка этих правил все еще остается 80.54% среди всех юзеров.

Comment: Согласен, я вообще о них не думаю... Я давно от них отказался... Даже не заморачиваюсь... Но предупредить, на мой взгляд  ты должен, мало ли, человек не опытный не сообразил сразу... А потом ему надо будет долго и нудно все переделывать...  И тем более, что именно в данном случае в списке  FF. И  имеет большое значение